# contour plot of function

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I have the function

$$f(x,y) = x^{2/3}+y^{2/3} $$

I'm looking to map contour lines.

As usual - I have substituted $f$ with a constant $c$.

Usually what I would do is try to isolate one of the variables to get a better picture, but here it does not seem to work.

A graphing calculator brought up a pinched square shape, but I just can't understand the logical way to get to this shape.

Any ideas how to simplify this problem?

Comment: Start with $f(x,y) = c =  1$. Clearly $(1,0), (0,1)$ are end points. Then to convince yourself it is a 'pinched square', try $x = 1/4, 1/2, 3/4$ or more values. Then think about what happens when  $c$ is scaled up or down. Also, you can solve algebraically for $x$ or $y$. Also: is there a restriction on the domains of $x,y$? There's an ambiguity about $x^{2/3}, y^{2/3}$ for negative values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can see clearly now the points that $f$ cuts the axes. Solving leaves me with a very ugly and messy solution. I'm having trouble seeing the curve between the points. How would negative values affect it? There is a square there so all the values are positive. Thanks!

Comment: hint: if $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ then the contour map would consist of circles centred on the origin with radius = $\sqrt c$ and you would get the formulas $y=\pm (c-x^2)^\frac 12$

Comment: This I know, but I don't see how it translates to this question.

Answer (score 2):

> *A graphing calculator brought up a pinched square shape, but I just can't understand the logical way to get to this shape.*

$\qquad\quad$ Geometric shapes described by algebraic equations of the form $|x|^n+|y|^n=r^n$ are called [superellipses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse). For $n=1$, we have a diamond square, determined by four straight line segments. For $n>1$, these $4$ lines begin to bend outwards, forming a convex shape. Thus, $n=2$ yields a circle, for instance. Letting $n<1$ makes the lines bend inwards, and thus the resulting shape is concave. The case $n=\dfrac23$ in particular is called an [astroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid). Note that the irreducible even numerator makes the absolute value signs redundant.